# Arrange Stylus properties in alphabetical order

Tags: stylus

I'm just wondering if there's any way to arrange Stylus properties in alphabetical order, preferably something I can add to my development build process? For what it's worth, I'm using minimal markup with Stylus, dropping all semicolons, braces etc. Thanks.